# How can I add proper memoization to optimize this recursive algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am looking at [this leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) where I write a function that takes an array of numbers and output the biggest sum of non-contiguous sub-arrays.

For example, if the array is `[1,2,3,1]`, the output is `4` because `1 + 3`
if the array is `[2,7,9,3,1]` the output is `12` because `2 + 9 + 1 = 12`

Here is my attempt:

```js
var rob = function (nums) {
  const recurse = (index, path) => {
    if (index >= nums.length) return path.reduce((sum, i) => sum + nums[i], 0)

    let rob = -Infinity
    if (index !== path.at(-1) + 1) {
      rob = recurse(index + 1, path.concat(index))
    }

    const notRob = recurse(index + 1, path)

    return Math.max(rob, notRob)
  }

  return recurse(0, [])
}

rob([1,2,3,1]) // 4
rob([2,7,9,3,1]) // 12
```

This function works but it times out on Leetcode as it didn't have memorization to optimize repeated calculations. So I added one where the cache key is the `index`:

```js
var rob = function (nums) {
  const memo = new Map()

  const recurse = (index, path) => {
    if (index >= nums.length) return path.reduce((sum, i) => sum + nums[i], 0)
    if (memo.has(index)) {
      return memo.get(index)
    }

    let rob = -Infinity
    if (index !== path.at(-1) + 1) {
      rob = recurse(index + 1, path.concat(index))
    }

    const notRob = recurse(index + 1, path)
    const max = Math.max(rob, notRob)
    memo.set(index, Math.max(rob, notRob))

    return max
  }

  return recurse(0, [])
}
```

Now this solution is no longer correct. For example, with `rob([1, 3, 1])` it outputs `2` instead of `3`.

I can't wrap my head around why this memorization is incorrect. If I tweaked my implementation slightly, this very same memorization ends up working just fine:

```js
var rob2 = function (nums) {
  const memo = new Map()
  const recur = (index) => {
    if (index >= nums.length) return 0
    if (memo.has(index)) return memo.get(index)
    const rob = nums[index] + recur(index + 2)
    const notRob = recur(index + 1)
    const max = Math.max(rob, notRob)
    memo.set(index, max)
    return max
  }

  return recur(0)
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this happened? Also what is the time complexity **if** we don't add the memorization?

Comment: Maybe because in `[1, 3, 1]` only firs and last `1` is non-contiguous?

Answer (score 2):

[Edit for clarification]

The cache key was right, it's the value stored that was wrong : for each cache, you stored the value of the first solution you tried for the whole array. Let's take a look at what happened :

1. You call `recurse(0, [])`
2. **recurse(0, [])** -  You check `map[0]`, there is no value
3. **recurse(0, [])** -  You call `recurse(1,[0])` to compute `RoB`
4. **recurse(1, [0])** -  You check `map[1]`, there is no value
5. **recurse(1, [0])** - You set `RoB` at -inf
6. **recurse(1, [0])** - You call `recurse(2, [0])` to compute `notRoB`
7. **recurse(2, [0])** - You check `map[2]`, there is no value
8. **recurse(3, [0,2])** -You call `recurse(3,[0,2])` to compute `RoB`
9. **recurse(3, [0,2])** -`index > nums.length` -> you return the sum (`0 + 2 -> 2`)
10. **recurse(2, [0])** - You call recurse(3, [0]), to compute `notRoB`
11. **recurse(3, [0])** -`index > nums.length` -> you return the sum (`0 -> 0`)
12. **recurse(2, [0])** - You take the max of `RoB` and `notRoB` (0,2 -> 2)
13. **recurse(2, [0])** - You store the max in the cache and return it (`map[2] = 2)`
14. **recurse(1, [0])** - You take the max of `RoB` and `notRob` (-inf, 2 -> 2)
15. **recurse(1, [0])** - You store the max in the cache, and return it (`map[1] = 2`)
16. **recurse(0, [])** - You call `recurse(1,[])` to compute `notRoB`
17. **recurse(1, [])** - You check `map[1]`, you find `2` and return it
18. **recurse(0, [])** - You take the max of `RoB` and `notRoB` (2,2 -> 2)
19. **recurse(0, [])** - You store the max in cache and return it (`map[0] = 2`)
20. The solution found is 2.

The problem is that you compute the solution from start to finish (by using `path`), but store them from finish to start (first your store `map[2]`, then `map[1]`, etc.) but you use `path` for the value. That means that the stored value is set to the first solution you try, thus all solution will have the same value.

[End of edit]

There is 2 main problem with your first solution :

- First, the memoization is wrong : the value you set is the total of the numbers taken before current index (`path` in your code). This should be best solution starting from current index (including index).
- Second, when you call `recurse(1, [0])`, you set the `map[1]`, even if you did not take the value at index 1. This means that anytime you'll look at this index in the future, you'll get the value of `recurse(2, [0])`, so you never compute `recurse(1, [])` properly.

Complexity without memoization is roughly O((1.6)^n) : if f(n) is the "number of actions" done for an array of n elements, then an array of n+1 will requier f(n-1) + f(n) actions. This is the fibonacci sequence, with a growth of (1.6)^n

Comment: hey could you elaborate on what you think the right cache key should be? I am not sure if I understand what you meant there? did you mean that it should be `index+ 1` instead of `index`?

Comment: can you elaborate what you meant by "best total of subarray after index (including index)." It'd be great if you can just modify the code

Comment: I added clarification, changed  "best total of subarray after index (including index)." to "best solution starting from current index (including index)." and made a step by step analysis of the first solution. I won't modify the code, as your second attempt is exactly what I would do.